# compiling google cloud service client library with guava

Tags: android, google-app-engine, gradle, guava

I'm using android studio. I'm developing an app with google cloud appengine (endpoints) and google cloud storage. When I write the gradle dependencies as shown:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-storage:v1beta2-rev77-1.20.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile project(path: ':backend', configuration: 'android-endpoints')


    compile files('libs/joda-time-2.8.2.jar')
    compile ('com.google.appengine.tools:appengine-gcs-client:0.4.4')
    compile files('libs/guava-18.0.jar')
}
```

I retrieve an error when compiling:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
 java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/common/reflect/TypeToken$TypeCollector$ForwardingTypeCollector.class
```

I've tried to exclue in this way

```
compile ('com.google.appengine.tools:appengine-gcs-client:0.4.4'){
    exclude group: 'com.google.guava'
}
```

But nothing works. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) First of all let's remove this ugly jars from your dependencies. I am about joda-time and guava

```
compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.8.2'  
compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
```

2) Move `exclude group: 'com.google.guava'` from `appengine` to `apis`

```
compile ('com.google.apis:google-api-services-storage:v1beta2-rev77-1.20.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.guava'
}
```

And add it to your `:backend`

```
compile (project(path: ':backend', configuration: 'android-endpoints')) {
    exclude group: 'com.google.guava'
}
```

3) Now you can get this error `com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '...java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1`
If yes we should add exclude to `appengine`

```
compile('com.google.appengine.tools:appengine-gcs-client:0.4.4') {
    exclude group: 'javax.transaction'
}
```

4) Now you get `Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/NOTICE.txt`
And this we solve with `packagingOptions` in `android {}` section

```
packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
}
```

So your final result

```
android {
    ...
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile (project(path: ':backend', configuration: 'android-endpoints')) {
        exclude group: 'com.google.guava'
    }

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.8.2'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'

    compile ('com.google.apis:google-api-services-storage:v1beta2-rev77-1.20.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.guava'
    }
    compile('com.google.appengine.tools:appengine-gcs-client:0.4.4') {
        exclude group: 'javax.transaction'
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but I get the same error after doing you said me. I share a screenshot of my gradle: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/25901081/error.png  https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/25901081/ForwardingTypeCollectors.png                                                                                                                      As you can see I've done just what you recommend me. :(

Comment: @RubénAvendañoCaballero did you extend your app from MultidexApplication? and set multidex to true?

Comment: @RubénAvendañoCaballero post you whole build.gradle

Comment: @RubénAvendañoCaballero exclude guava from appengine too. And give me dependencies of your backend module

Comment: Hi pengrad. I send you both build.gradle's. Nothing changes excluding guava from appengine. Thanks in advance. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/25901081/app_build_gradle.txt  https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/25901081/backend_build_gradle.txt

Comment: Hi. Last version of what library? I've changed to the last version of guava (19.0-rc1) and nothing changes. I show you the screenshot. Thanks.  https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/25901081/last%20version.png

Comment: @RubénAvendañoCaballero no, just look on my changes in answer, now everything is fine

Comment: @RubénAvendañoCaballero so?

Comment: It works! Thank you very much Pengrad, you are great. Now I have other issues, but I'll try to solve by my self.

Comment: @RubénAvendañoCaballero Vote UP, and set question as answered :)

Comment: Hi. Sorry but I'm still not able to compile my project. I'm still getting dependencies errors.                                                                      Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: javax/annotation/CheckForNull.class.   I've used exclude group: 'javax.annotation' but it doesn't seem to work. Can you help me?

Comment: @RubénAvendañoCaballero Did you add some new dependencies? Post new question with your latest build.gragle